# Can makefiles say "build target X and everything that depends on it" without building everything first?

Tags: makefile

If I have a Makefile, I can type `make`, change some source code, type `make` again and be sure that it won't needlessly rebuild the entire project; it'll just build the part that changed. Great.

How about if I want to avoid that first call to `make` because building everything in the `Makefile`, which may include many distinct relatively unrelated binaries is needlessly expensive or even impossible. Suppose I just typed `make clean` and changed some source code. I can build the specific thing I changed by saying `make that_specific_thing`. Is there a way to say "build that specific thing, but also anything that depends on it"?

To make that more concrete. Let's say I changed `myLibrary.cpp`, and now I want to have a way to say build everything that uses `myLibrary.cpp`, for example, some `unittest.cpp` that I've never heard of/seen in the Makefile before. I don't want to say `make my_liberary my_unittest`, because that requires me the human to figure out what should be built.

Is there a way to do this automatically? If yes, does it require structuring my Makefile in an atypical way?

Comment: Find the target you want to build. Then do `make target`. The makefile can define targets as dependencies so it sounds like your makefile requires alteration.

Comment: The thing is that "everything that depends on myLibrary.cpp, but I don't know exactly what that is, and don't include anything else" is very rarely what anyone actually wants to build.  `Make` doesn't have any support for that.  You tell it what you *do* want it build -- possibly implicitly by allowing it to choose the default target -- and `make` figures out how to do that.  If you don't know what you want to build, then why do you want to build it?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you just build the entire project then the target which depends on your `myLibrary.cpp` will be built again anyways. May be try building the entire project for the first time and then keep making changes to .cpp files and incremental build makes sense

Comment: @JohnBollinger as I understand it the complete build is prohibitively expensive and the OP wants to start some kind of incremental development in the middle of the dependency tree. If this is a wise way to work on software I can't tell. Concerning `make` I think it is quite complicated to realize such a thing because `make` can't guess pattern rules backwards, can it?

Comment: How expensive a full build may be is irrelevant to my point, @Vroomfondel.  If you're working on some component of a larger project, then surely you know what component that is, and therefore what it is you want to build, at least in an abstract sense.  If the scenario posited by the OP is ever encountered in practice, then it probably reflects an issue with the programmer's mental model of what they're trying to do.  "Build component X and its tests" is a reasonable thing to want to do.  "Build component_x.cpp and everything that depends on it" rarely is, in those terms.

Comment: @John Bollinger - you're assuming the file contains only one project, and that it's trivial in scope. Neither is true. It is a bad assumption that you know the details of the project, and even if you do, it'd still be convenient to say "build everything that needs to be built given my changes". The computer should be able to figure this out, why impose a human burden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as if your default target is `all`; I'll assume that.

```
make clean # you know what this does
make -t    # this doesn't actually run any recipes, it just touches all targets
make -w that_specific_thing # "what if" mode, as if that file were new
```

**EDIT:** If you also want to rebuild the *prerequisites* of `that_specific_thing`, you must add one more step:

```
make clean # whether you still need this depends on what you're trying to do
make that_specific_thing
make -t
make -w that_specific_thing
```

Comment: Thanks @Beta - this almost does what I want. It successfully builds the rules that depend on `that_specific_thing`, but not the stuff that `that_specific_thing` depends on. I tried to get around that with `make that_specific_thing && make -t && make -w that_specific_thing`, but the `make -t` call overwrites the output of `that_specific_thing` and the stuff it depends on with empty contents. Do you have a way to handle that component of the problem?

Comment: Side note: I'm giving a talk at CppCon where this is relevant. Do you have a preference with regards to whether I thank you for the help on stage? My inclination would be to do so, but I don't want to assume that's what you'd like.

Comment: @Mark: You didn't mention that in the Question, and it changes the problem quite a lot. But there is an elegant solution; I'll edit, As for being thanked on stage, I never get tired of that,